# Is there any way to sort how to sort a list of 3-element tuples

Tags: python, list, sorting, multidimensional-array, tuples

I have a list of 3-element tuples, something like this one:
lst = [(0, 0, 'C'), (0, 1, 'C'), (0, 2, 'C'), (0, 3, 'C'), (0, 4, 'C'), (1, 0, 'C'), (1, 4, 'C'), (1, 1, 'B'), (1, 2, 'B'), (1, 3, 'B'), (2, 0, 'C'), (2, 4, 'C'), (2, 1, 'B'), (2, 3, 'B'), (2, 2, 'A'), (3, 0, 'C'), (3, 4, 'C'), (3, 1, 'B'), (3, 2, 'B'), (3, 3, 'B'), (4, 0, 'C'), (4, 1, 'C'), (4, 2, 'C'), (4, 3, 'C'), (4, 4, 'C')]
The first two elements are row,column and the third one the letter I should print in those coordinates.

I managed to sort an unsorted raw list by row (the list above) using the sorted function with a lambda function as a key parameter, but when trying to sort the columns I got myself in the bushes.
I need to sort the two first elements so that they form a matrix like this (0,1,"C"),(0,2,"C"),(0,3,"C"),(0,4,"C"),(1,0,"C"),(1,1,"B"),(1,2,"B"),(1,3,"B"),(1,4,"C"), and so on...
Thanks for your advice on this.

Comment: Maybe `print(sorted(lst))` is that you want?

Comment: Hi! I can't help but notice that this question is completely out of context, to the point that you sound like you're talking about a particular programming language, but you didn't actually specify which language that was. Is it python?

Comment: I've edited to add tag python. If this question is not about python, you can [edit] again, or you can [rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75605919/revisions) my edit.

Comment: The default sort order for tuples is element by element - first part, then second part, then third.

Comment: Can you include the line where you sorted successfully with a lambda? I don't think you need the lambda at all in the row case. In any case, it would help us write answers in the same form as your question.

Comment: Sorry about missing that important tag. Yes, it is Python.

Answer (score 2):

A simple sort of these tuples will order them in row/column sequence.  Based on those sorted values, you can build the resulting matrix by slicing the list.

```
lst.sort()

M = [ [V for _,_,V in row] for row in zip(*[iter(lst)]*(lst[-1][1]+1)) ]

print(*M,sep="\n")

['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
['C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C']
['C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C']
['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

- Once the list is sorted in row/col order, the last item has the largest row and column number, so it can be used to determine the size of each row (by adding 1 to the column number): `(lst[-1][1]+1)`
- To slice the list you can use zip() by giving it an iterator that you repeat as many times as there are columns.  Each tuple returned by zip will contain the next N values, effectively producing rows.
- Since you only want the matrix to contain the letters of the tuples, the third element of the tuples are extracted using a nested list comprehension: `[V for _,_,V in row]`

To make it easier to manage, you could break down the process into smaller steps:

```
lst.sort()
width      = lst[-1][1]+1               # number of columns
_,_,values = zip(*lst)                  # values (letters) only
slices     = zip(*[iter(values)]*width) # slice into list of row tuples
matrix     = list(map(list,slices))     # convert row slices to list of lists

print(*matrix,sep="\n")

['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
['C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C']
['C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C']
['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

*Note that building the matrix this way requires that `lst` contain one tuple for every cell in the matrix.*

...

*If `lst` doesn't contain values for every coordinate, then the matrix must be pre-existing (i.e not created from the list). There would be no guaranty that the coordinates in `lst` always go up to the last row or column so we couldn't reliably compute the dimensions based on the list.  Given this, there would be no point in sorting the list beforehand, an assignment loop would suffice to update cells in the existing matrix*

Another fun way to build the matrix is to use the groupby function from itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby

rows,_,values = map(iter,zip(*sorted(lst)))
M = [ row for _,[*row,] in groupby(values,lambda _:next(rows)) ]

print(*M,sep="\n")
['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
['C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C']
['C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C']
['C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C']
['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

Comment: I would have upvoted just for `print(*M,sep="\n")` alone

Answer (score 1):

You are asking two distinct questions. I will answer both.

> Is there any way to sort how to sort a list of 3-element tuples?

Yes there is. Just use `sorted`. See [Python Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

```py
lst = [(3, 0, 'C'), (0, 3, 'C'), (2, 2, 'A'), (3, 4, 'C'), (1, 3, 'B'), (0, 0, 'C'), (0, 4, 'C'), (0, 1, 'C'), (3, 2, 'B'), (4, 4, 'C'), (4, 2, 'C'), (1, 4, 'C'), (2, 1, 'B'), (1, 1, 'B'), (4, 0, 'C'), (4, 3, 'C'), (2, 3, 'B'), (4, 1, 'C'), (0, 2, 'C'), (3, 3, 'B'), (2, 4, 'C'), (1, 2, 'B'), (1, 0, 'C'), (2, 0, 'C'), (3, 1, 'B')]

lst.sort()

print(lst)
# [(0, 0, 'C'), (0, 1, 'C'), (0, 2, 'C'), (0, 3, 'C'), (0, 4, 'C'),
#  (1, 0, 'C'), (1, 1, 'B'), (1, 2, 'B'), (1, 3, 'B'), (1, 4, 'C'),
#  (2, 0, 'C'), (2, 1, 'B'), (2, 2, 'A'), (2, 3, 'B'), (2, 4, 'C'),
#  (3, 0, 'C'), (3, 1, 'B'), (3, 2, 'B'), (3, 3, 'B'), (3, 4, 'C'),
#  (4, 0, 'C'), (4, 1, 'C'), (4, 2, 'C'), (4, 3, 'C'), (4, 4, 'C')]
```

> The first two elements are row,column and the third one the letter I should print in those coordinates.

Just build a 2d array `a` of the appropriate dimensions, initially filled with zeroes. Then iterate on the triplets `(row, column, element)` and affect `element` to `a[row][column]`.

```py
lst = [(3, 0, 'C'), (0, 3, 'C'), (2, 2, 'A'), (3, 4, 'C'), (1, 3, 'B'), (0, 0, 'C'), (0, 4, 'C'), (0, 1, 'C'), (3, 2, 'B'), (4, 4, 'C'), (4, 2, 'C'), (1, 4, 'C'), (2, 1, 'B'), (1, 1, 'B'), (4, 0, 'C'), (4, 3, 'C'), (2, 3, 'B'), (4, 1, 'C'), (0, 2, 'C'), (3, 3, 'B'), (2, 4, 'C'), (1, 2, 'B'), (1, 0, 'C'), (2, 0, 'C'), (3, 1, 'B')]

height = 1+max(row for row,_,_ in lst)
width = 1+max(col for _,col,_ in lst)
a = [[0 for col in range(width)] for row in range(height)]
for row, col, element in lst:
    a[row][col] = element
print(a)
# [['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
#  ['C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
#  ['C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
#  ['C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
#  ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']]
```

Note that you can actually combine the two methods.

Since you have a 5x5 array to fill, and your list has exactly 25 elements, then once the elements are sorted, you don't need to remember the `row` and `col` indices, you can just split the list every 5 elements:

```py
lst = [(3, 0, 'C'), (0, 3, 'C'), (2, 2, 'A'), (3, 4, 'C'), (1, 3, 'B'), (0, 0, 'C'), (0, 4, 'C'), (0, 1, 'C'), (3, 2, 'B'), (4, 4, 'C'), (4, 2, 'C'), (1, 4, 'C'), (2, 1, 'B'), (1, 1, 'B'), (4, 0, 'C'), (4, 3, 'C'), (2, 3, 'B'), (4, 1, 'C'), (0, 2, 'C'), (3, 3, 'B'), (2, 4, 'C'), (1, 2, 'B'), (1, 0, 'C'), (2, 0, 'C'), (3, 1, 'B')]

width = 5  #  = 1+max(col for _,col,_ in lst)
a = [e for _,_,e in sorted(lst)]
a = [a[i:i+width] for i in range(0,len(a),width)]
print(a)
# [['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
#  ['C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
#  ['C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
#  ['C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
#  ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']]
```